# CSS background image in flex container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need to put a background image to a text. I suspect it could be because we nested too many classes in "div" but still can't figure it out.

CSS:

```
.box {
  display: flex;
  top: 80px;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 30px;
  border-top: thin solid black;
  border-bottom: thin solid black;
  border-right: thin solid black;
  border-left: thin solid black;
}

.box1 {
  padding-left: 300px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  width: 630px;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.smalltitle2 {
  border-bottom: medium solid black;
  background-image: url("https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-news-bite.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="box1">
    <div class="smalltitle2">Mother of Three Buys Tuna Steak at Phish Concert. Leaves, "Feeling Funny."</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the background is visible, simply change its position or size. try `backround-size:contain` and you will see it

Comment: If the answer I posted helped you out and solved your problem, make sure to mark it up. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a width and height to your smalltitle2 container and you can tweak around how you want to make it look whether it should be part of the image, or do you want the entire image inside the container (make use of `background-size`).

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  top: 80px;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 30px;
  border-top: thin solid black;
  border-bottom: thin solid black;
  border-right: thin solid black;
  border-left: thin solid black;
}

.box1 {
  padding-left: 300px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  width: 630px;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.smalltitle2 {
  border-bottom: medium solid black;
  background:url(https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-news-bite.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="box1">
    <div class="smalltitle2">Mother of Three Buys Tuna Steak at Phish Concert. Leaves, "Feeling Funny."</div>   
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either try `background-size: contain;` or `background-size: cover;` etc.

There is no problem with the CSS, it's just missing a rule to define the size of your background image.

See demo here : https://jsfiddle.net/v8eLsef4/1/